# How to make user not be part of Users group in Windows?

Tags: windows, permissions, users, user-groups

I want to restrict some users from having default privileges of Users group, unless they are manually allowed. Unfortunately, when I remove them from this group manually, they still get Users SID as seen in WHOAMI /ALL:
           Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
BUILTIN\Users                                 Alias            S-1-5-32-545

I don't want to change ACLs, because this action should be part of my program installation, and I don't want my program to change default ACLs across all drives to function.

Comment: I don't believe a User can't be in a group.  So I would simply create a group based on the User group and simply change the user's group when you want to give access to those privileges in question.

Comment: I put new users into their own group, but they still get BUILTIN\Users SID. What do you mean by "create group based on the Users"?

Comment: It means exactly what I said.  Create a new user group with the exact permissions you want.  When you want grant permissions to the exception change the user group of those users.

Comment: The problem is even if I assign users to group Bla, they will have also permissions granted to BUILTIN\Users, which I don't want